# Are there any restrictions on what rolls can benefit from 'Good time management'?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, extended-actions

The **Good Time Management** merit (from *God-Machine Chronicles Rules Update*) lets me reduce the time between rolls in an extended action by half.

Is there any limit on this? Does it apply to contested rolls, such as chase scene? If so, how? What about on rolls like picking a lock where there might be an implied physical limitation to the speed of your actions?

Or am I expected to  be sensible, and only apply it to a subset of skills?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're always expected to be sensible. :) But it applies to extended contested rolls, too, so long as they are mundane actions. (It does not apply to non-extended contested rolls, naturally.)

So, yes, it would apply to a car chase. You take advantage of quick shifts in lights and traffic; you roll with the changes better. However, since car chases don't take very long to begin with, the savings in minutes and seconds are minimal. It definitely applies to picking a lock.

To the issue of your follow-up question in the comments:

> But does that mean I get twice as many rolls as the other contestant? How does time management affect picking locks or what about 'climbing'?

You don't get more rolls than your opponent, if you have one; it's that half the time is taken between each roll, so the whole affair is completed faster. It's for making the extended action take less time, not getting a speed advantage in the contested part.

Comment: But does that mean I get twice as many rolls as the other contestee ? How does time management effect picking locks or what about 'climbing'? Why are 'steely nerves' being equated to 'good time management'?

Comment: I've included your comment in the answer and updated it.

Comment: @Pureferret Why "steely nerves"? It's a reflection of the original merit, which mentioned "training in a corporate environment" to deal with unexpected changes. Since you've clarified that you're using the GMC version, which strips that, I'll remove the reference.

Comment: It was because you mentioned 'steely nerves' only. To me my only issue is the name implies a subset of what it actually does. I don't see how you can 'time manage' chasing someone on foot. And I was worried the RAI did not match RAW.

Comment: Also, my point about for  rolls stands. Say you are in a contested, extended roll situation hacking a database and someone is trying to  stop you. Each roll is separated by ten minutes. Except you halve that,  so you roll at 5, 10, 15, 20 minutes. They (having not-so-good time management)  roll at 10 and 20 minutes. With the same dice pool you've rolled twice as many dice sdice they have. Is this RAI or RAW?

Comment: Also in the car/ foot chase example (cmiir) but you advance a set number of metres per successful roll, as you roll twice as often, you advance twice as often in the same time step. Thus your car is now traveling twice as fast.

Comment: @Pureferret That's not how a car or foot chase works; as per page 65 of the nWoD core, both the pursuer and the pursued are striving to reach a number of successes equal to the pursued's Speed total. If the pursued reaches the total without the pursuer exceeding his successes at any point, they escape. There's no tie between successes in the chase and the velocity of the traveller.

Comment: @Pureferret I wouldn't allow GTM to be used in the hacker/counterhacker situation you describe; that's more like combat than an contested challenge. If you and the other hacker were trying to both hack different computers, or were hacking the same computer and wanted to see who got in first, then it'd be appropriate.

Comment: is like to revisit this question.  In your having example,  as my rolls take half as long,  I would finish in half the time. If I that was successful I would always beat you... Even if all my successes came in the last roll. That to me seems over powered.

Comment: Feel free to expand or alter the question in that case; perhaps it will draw better or more comprehensive answers?